# Can I use a JMeter Duration Assertion with a variable?

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to assert the response time of several pages but introducing a threshold, let's say:

- http://xxxx/login typical takes: 500ms
- http://xxxx/user typical takes: 1000ms
- ...

So I want to write assertions checking the expected value + threshold, i.e. something like:

- http://xxxx/login: Assert < 500 * (1 + ${threshold})
- http://xxxx/user: Assert < 1000 * (1 + ${threshold})
- ...

For sure I can make the calculation and set the value, but would be nice if I can use a variable.

Would this be possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, you can perform whatever calculation you want using i.e. [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) which allows executing arbitrary [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) code.

In your case the code would be:

```
500 * (1 + (vars.get('threshold') as int))
```

and the __groovy() function syntax:

```
${__groovy(500 * (1 + (vars.get('threshold') as int)),)}
```

You can put the function directly to your Duration Assertion:

[image]

and the function will be evaluated in the runtime and applied to the Duration Assertion:

[image]

In the above example `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, it provides read/write access to all [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in the current virtual user context, see JavaDoc for available functions and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) for more information on this and other JMeter API shorthands available for JSR223 Test Elements and __groovy() function